# Jquery dialog submit validation

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-ui

I need someone to put me through how I can use jquery dialog to ask "Confirm" or "Cancel" validations before submit.  I get *Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'* for this on IE9:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#savechanges").click(function () {

        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    $("#myformid").submit();
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });         
        return false;
    });
});
</script>


<div id="dialog"></div>


 <p>
    <input type="submit" id="savechanges" value="Save changes" />
</p>
```

Comment: check if your plugin JS file is successfully downloaded or not.

Comment: Is your form's id is correct? It has to be 'myformid'

Answer (score 0):

If you set `autoOpen` as `false`, dialogbox doesn't open when you define it. So you should set it `true`.

From jQuery-UI docs,

```
autoOpen

When autoOpen is true the dialog will open automatically when dialog is called. 
If false it will stay hidden until .dialog("open") is called on it.
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p5FuX/3/)

Comment: The issue mentioned is not with `autoopen`, rather the browser cannot find the `dialog` definition in JS.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reason behind this issue, make use of any debug tool like firebug to check

1. Use a tool like Firebug for Firefox to verify each JS file is being included.
2. Make sure there is no other JS on the page that could cause an error.
3. Verify you have the correct versions of the files downloaded.